# Installation on Linux & Win7: Aptana, PostgreSQL, Ruby, JQuery (WWW on Apache)

Tags: jquery, ruby, postgresql, windows-7, debian

Basically I have 2 systems, where I want to develop (and use) my application:

1. A Linux (Debian) system. This is my server. Here I have PostgreSQL (& phpPgAdmin), Apache, Ruby. Typically I use this system from remote, using a DynDNS-Service (this is working fine). Note: Usually I do my SW-Installations there via apt-get (so: No Source-Code).
2. A Windows 7 Notebook, which is my "working-system", my client. Here I have Aptana-Studio, Ruby ( & also a PostgreSQL-DB). (Actually I don't want to install Eclipse)

What I intend to do: Develop, test (and use) a Web-Application on my Notebook; using Aptana-Studio, PostgreSQL (remotely @ Linux), Ruby (on Rails) & JQuery.

Where I am confused about:

1. Where do I have to install what?
2. And what do I have to configure & how?
3. Are there special drivers (or add-ons) I need, for this to work?  If yes: Where shall I install them?

Can somebody please help me?

Comment: If you already have these things installed, why are you asking about installation? Configuring what?

Comment: One example: I expected, that I could configure my DB-Connection (as mentioned: PostgreSQL on remote Debian-Server) in my new Aptana-Project. But I can't: I don't see such an option. So I guess, that something is missing. But what?

To me it seems: I have all the bits and pieces installed, but not the connections between them :-)

Comment: Maybe I should be more specific. Step by step. So my question No. 1 is:

I created a new (still empty) rails-project in Aptana Studio 3. Now I want to I configure my DB-Connection (a postgreSQL-DB on a remote Debian-Server).

Help I find talk about a "Database-perspecitve", which I should open. But a thing like this does not exist.

Other help talk about an Add-On (Quantum DB); but this is related to Aptana 2 (I have 3) and, anyway, I don't find a button to include AddOns.